# Loop through multiple select lists and count the number of times each option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Part of a site I'm working on involves creating repeat instances of the same select - option.  I would like to count the number of times each option has been selected, and then store that number as a variable, which can then be sent to php email function.

For example - if "Infallid" is selected 3 times - I get infallid = 3, and 0 for the others.

JS fiddle showing how it all works - https://jsfiddle.net/scx4shnd/2/

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("select[name='diskho'] > option:selected").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
    // should alert - "value 1 = x" , "value 2 = "y" ect" where x and y are different values (numbers)
});
$("select[name='spishall'] > option:selected").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
});
```

Comment: Does that replace the alert part?

Comment: That's before the last }); ? I have tried that but getting 0.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scx4shnd/4/

Comment: I would like to get the total number of times each option is selected, for example if Infälld is selected 2 times i get Infälld = 2 ect.

Comment: Currently it's giving me 1 in an alert box each time a value is repeated

Answer (score 2):

You can use following logic to calculate the number of times an option has been selected:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var dishkoMap = {};
    $("select[name='diskho'] > option:selected").each(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        if (dishkoMap[value]) { // if value already exists then increase it by 1
            dishkoMap[value] += 1;
        } else {
            dishkoMap[value] = 1;
        }
    });
    // dishkoMap is a dictionary object so you won't see anything in alert.
    // open the browser console and you can see the counts corresponding
    // to each selected option
    console.log(dishkoMap);

});
```

Similarly, you can also write for `Spishäll` and `Blandare`.

I would suggest writing a function where you pass the name of the `select` and then return the countMap.

```
function getCountMap(name) {
    var countMap = {};
    $("select[name='" + name + "'] > option:selected").each(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        if (countMap[value]) { // if value already exists then increase it by 1
            countMap[value] += 1;
        } else {
            countMap[value] = 1;
        }
    });
    return countMap;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
var dishkoMap = getCountMap('dishko');
var spishallMap = getCountMap('spishall');
// etc.
```

Comment: Would it be better if the select name is "diskho" for all  or "diskho1 (incrementing each new select box added?) , ect?

Comment: You can see that when the name is dishko we can just write this function `getCountMap` but otherwise you will need something else e.g. a className using which you can access all the selects related to `dishko` in one go.

Comment: I have managed to successfully do the first part, however I'm unable to get anything for Function getCountMap

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on what you weren't able to do with the function?

Comment: I am not sure about the exact details but I have figured it out using another method.